# How to transform texture stencil correctly?

Tags: texture-painting

When I press Shift + Y or X to transform texture and right mouse button (+ Alt for texture mask), It is start acting strange. On the link is what I want, 19:57:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lqak2bFkpA&t=1197s Lizard Mage: Modelling, Texturing, Rigging (Blender Timelapse)

And this is what I have:

[image]